# PHP define and echo result

Tags: php, mysql

How to define data from database if i have in database table this as result `s,d,r,t` ?

Here is the screen from table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/liaGO.png

I can do this if i have only **s** in database

```
if($func->data =='s') {echo "This is S";}
```

I need to define every letters in table and echo result, but how ? if i have more than one letters how i can do this?

Comment: Do you want to return a column from mysql table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
$letters = explode(',', strtolower($func->data));

if (in_array('s', $letters)) echo 'This is S';
if (in_array('d', $letters)) echo 'This is D';
if (in_array('r', $letters)) echo 'This is R';
if (in_array('t', $letters)) echo 'This is T';
if (in_array('e', $letters)) echo 'This is E';
```